# Could not get unknown property 'compile'

Tags: android

Got this error when I created a new blank activity ,before that everything worked fine in the app ,it was working and no gradle issues :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ie.example.artur.adminapp"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin')

        //Retrofit



       compile
        'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'compile
        'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'compile
        'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'compile
        'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'compile
        'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

This is the error that I got :

```
 Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    <a href="openFile:C:\Users\family\Desktop\AdminApp-1-v2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `compile '<NAME OF PACKAGE>'` not `'<NAME OF PACKAGE>' compile` as you have in several lines. Also, you have a `compile` alone on it's line which cause the error you are seing.

Comment: @litelite yeah that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your syntax of dependency.

To fix it, modify your dependency-code to:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin')

//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```